# relation between batch_size and running time

Tags: python, keras

previously I thought that smaller batch_size would lead to faster training, but in practice in keras, I am receiving the opposite results which is that bigger batch_size make training faster.

I am implementing a sample code, and by increasing the amount of batch_size, the training become faster. that is the opposite of my previously common believe (that smaller batch_size results in faster training),
here's the sample code:

```
# fit model
import time
start = time.time()
history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=1000,
batch_size= 500 , verbose=0)
end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start
print(elapsed)
```

I put 500, 250, 50 and 10 as batch_size respectively, i expect the lower batch_size would have faster training, but batch_size 500 results in 6.3 sec,
250 results in 6.7sec, 50 results in 28.0sec, and 10 results in 140.2secc !!!

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense. I do not know what model you are using but Keras is highly optimized making use of vectorization for fast matrix operations. So if you split your data of 5000 samples into batch sizes of 500, with 1000 epochs, essentially there are (5000/500) x 1000 iterations through the model. That's 10 000
Now if you do that for a batch size of 10 there are (5000/10) x 1000 iterations. That's 500 000. Many more iterations through the model, both forward and backwards.

Hope that helps.

Comment: but what about the idea of stochastic gradient descent? it has been said that smaller batch_size should end with faster training. isn't this true? is there any misconception here?

Comment: A smaller batch size can help reach convergence faster. However, in your question set up, you are giving a defined number of iterations through the data and a defined number of samples over which to train. Nowhere have you stated to end training when a certain threshold is reached. So it may, or may not have converged, but model fitting will continue. I would utilise a callback when fitting your model to terminate training once you are within a defined threshold. The Keras docs explain it and there are numerous tutorials. If you struggle to figure it out let me know and I can dig out a snippet

Answer (score 0):

For hardware, GPUs are very good at parallelising the calculations, specifically, the matrix operations happens in forward-and-backward-propagation. The same thing happens in software side, tensorflow and other DL libraies optimise matrix operations.

Therefore, lager batch size makes the GPU and DL libraries able to "optimise more matrix computation", which leads to faster training time.

Comment: my question is about a misconception about the idea of stochastic gradient descent, which says that smaller batch_size results in faster training. so if that is not the case, what is the advantage of stochastic gradient descent? or even minibatch gradient descent? because here as i explained, batch gradient descent is way more faster

Comment: You are totally right, SGD do converge faster than gradient descent. However, when the batch size is TOO small, the gradient of batch will not be a good estimation of optimal gradient, also, it will not be able to utilise the optimisation of matrix computation provided by GPUs and libraries. So, batch size should not be too large, and not too small!  There should be a sweet point of batch size which take a perfect balance of both side.

Comment: Small batch size takes less number of computation, but with longer time per computation. Large batch size takes more computation, but with shorter time per computation.

Comment: tnx, i got it, but i think in your last comment, you should substitute small batch size and large batch size. because i think small batch size takes more number of computation (updates) with shorter time per computation. and large batch size takes less computation (updates) but with longer time per computation.

Comment: Actually no. What I meant is small batch size takes smaller amount of matrix operations until it *converge* (that’s the point of SGD), but at the same time, small batch size cannot utilise the optimisation of matrix computation provided by GPUs and libraries. Therefore it take more time per computation. Noted that matrix computation =\= update, big batch takes more matrix computation to do a gradient update than smaller one.